# Nesting level limit error in SQL Server 2014

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2014

We have the following SQL Server stored procedure:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[up_get_id]
    (@KeyName VARCHAR(30), @ID INTEGER OUTPUT)
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @SEQ_NAME VARCHAR(120);
    SET @SEQ_NAME = 'seq_dbk_' + @KeyName;

    DECLARE @SQL NVARCHAR(1000);
    SET @SQL = 'set @ID = next value for ' + @SEQ_NAME;

    EXEC sp_executesql @SQL, N'@ID int out', @ID = @ID output;

    RETURN 0;
END
GO
```

Sometimes (not always, probably under high loading) after calling the stored procedure:

```
declare @P1 int
exec up_get_id  @KeyName = 'KEY', @ID = @P1 output
select @P1 Result
```

the client is getting an error:

> Warning: Fatal error 217 occurred at Nov 21 20117 12:54PM. Note the error and time, and contact your system administrator.

Also, the following message appears in SQL Server log:

> Maximum stored procedure, function, trigger, or view nesting level exceeded (limit 2).

Any ideas of what is wrong?

Server version:

```
Microsoft SQL Server 2014 - 12.0.4213.0 (X64)   
Jun 9 2015 12:06:16   
Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation  
Enterprise Edition (64-bit) on Windows NT 6.3 <X64> (Build 9600: ) (Hypervisor)
```

Comment: Exactly written "limit 2"? show full sql error with number and object

Comment: Yes, exactly "limit 2", it's not a typo. Actually, there are 2 error messages: 1st (getting by the client): "Warning: Fatal error 217 occurred ... " and 2nd which appears only in SQL Server Log: "Error: 217, Severity: 39, State: 16. Maximum stored procedure, function, trigger, or view nesting level exceeded (limit 2)."

Comment: "Severity: 39" does not happen in sql. See sql log

Comment: As I already said this message is from SQL Server log. I agree 2 things are very strange there: 1) "limit 2" 2) "Severity: 39"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Аnd unanswered response :)

If COMPATIBILITY_LEVEL 100 and less error

> Maximum stored procedure, function, trigger, or view nesting level
>   exceeded (limit 2).

110 and more

> NEXT VALUE FOR function cannot be used if ROWCOUNT option has been
>   set, or the query contains TOP or OFFSET.

So you set ROWCOUNT <> 0